# Validate and apply coupon when create an order programmatically

Tags: magento2, sales-order, quote, coupon, coupon-codes

I create an order programmatically like this:

```
$store = $this->storeManager->getStore();
$websiteId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
$customer = $this->_customerFactory->create();
$customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
$customer->loadByEmail($email); 
$quote = $this->quote->create();  
$quote->setStore($store);  
$customer = $this->_customerRepoInterface->getById($customer->getEntityId());
$quote->setCurrency();
$quote->assignCustomer($customer);  

foreach ($productsOrder as $productOrder) {
  $productId = $productOrder['product_id'];
  $qty = $productOrder['qty'];
  $product = $this->_product->load($productId);
  $price = $product->getPrice();
  $product->setPrice($price);
  $quote->addProduct(
      $product,
      intval($qty)
    );
}

$quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($address);
$quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($address);

$shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
$shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
  ->collectShippingRates()
  ->setShippingMethod($shippingMethod);  
$quote->setPaymentMethod($paymentMethod);  
$quote->setInventoryProcessed(false);  
$quote->save(); 

$quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => $paymentMethod]);

$quote->collectTotals()->save();

$order = $this->quoteManagement->submit($quote);
```

how can i apply coupon code in here and validate the coupon code?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to quote

```
$quote->setCouponCode($couponCode)->save()
```

after `$quote->save();`

Comment: how to validate the coupon code ?

Comment: I have to check